# inspecting / forensics on an exe

Tags: c++, windows, exe, reverse-engineering

our company acquired another company and one of the products is a C++ exe, the original developer is not available and  we don;t have the source code. We do have the exe.
What can I do to explore the exe? inspect it? maybe reverse engineer it
I was thinking of using regedit to see whether it works with the registry, maybe trying visual studio.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you have any lawyers in house?

Comment: If you´re unsure if you need Visual Studio or Regedit, give up. It will take to long.

Answer (score 2):

You could try ProcMon if you want to monitor what files/registry/etc it accesses.

For the program itself, there are disassemblers that can at least convert it back into assembly language. But depending on the size and complexity of the program that's probably not too helpful.

There might be tools that can attempt to convert it back into something resembling C or C++ code. I've heard of such things being attempted, but I really don't know how effective they've ever been. However I know that even if they worked at all, the results wouldn't have any variable or function names.

Whether assembly or something higher level, that would leave a lot of work left to a human to figure out what's going on in the program. That investment of time and effort might be better spent developing a completely new replacement according to whatever kind of specifications or behavior that is hopefully documented or else can be observed.